# How can I get when state change from other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I have a `settings.js`

```
constructor (props) {
 super(props);

 this.state = { 
   //default settings
   darkTheme: false
 };

 this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
}
```

this my `settings.js` constructor

```
handleToggle(event) {
 localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', this.state.darkTheme);
 this.setState({darkTheme: !this.state.darkTheme});
}
```

I`m change like this

So I have another component it's name  `main.js`. And I want to use when darkTheme changed I wanna get from my `main.js`

```
import Settings from '../containers/settings';
export default class Main extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state ={
    isDark: 
   }
  }

   updateTheme(isDark) {
    // Settings just toggled the theme!
   this.setState({isDark: isDark});
   }

   render() {
    return (
     <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={ 
      getMuiTheme(isDark === true ? 
      darkBaseTheme : null) }>
      <Paper zDepth={2}>
        <AppBar />
        <List />
      </Paper>
     </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```

So what is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this would be to have `Main.js` pass a function to `Settings.js` through props.

Main.js:

```
updateTheme(isDark) {
  // Settings just toggled the theme!
}

render() {
  ...
  <Settings updateTheme={this.updateTheme} />
  ...
}
```

Settings.js:

```
handleToggle(event) {
 localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', this.state.darkTheme);
 this.setState({darkTheme: !this.state.darkTheme}, () => {
   this.props.updateTheme(this.state.darkTheme);
 });
}
```

Comment: It's looks work Thank you for that. But I just use only boolean value if use like that also my settings component include some jsx like a view. So I have to use like this ?  `<Settings updateTheme={this.updateTheme} /> ` Its render also same jsx code

Comment: Yes you would use `<Settings updateTheme={this.updateTheme} />` in `Main.js`. Can you post your code for `Main.js`? That would help me understand your question.

Comment: I've updated my post please take a look. `getMuiTheme(isDark === true ? 
      darkBaseTheme : null) }>` I just use like this.

Comment: @UğurErdal Okay thanks for posting. `<Settings />` needs to be in the render method of `Main`. If you can't put it there, then you'll have to use something like Redux to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the relation between both components:
if they are like father and son, one contains anthor, the best practice is to connect via callback that passed via props.
If they are not related at all, it seems like typical case for using Redux.